# Getting a score of zero using cross val score

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to use cross_val_score on my dataset, but I keep getting zeros as the score:

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Flaveria.csv")
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["N level", "species"], drop_first=True)

# Extracting the target value from the dataset
X = df.iloc[:, df.columns != "Plant Weight(g)"]
y = np.array(df.iloc[:, 0], dtype="S6")

logreg = LogisticRegression()
loo = LeaveOneOut()

scores = cross_val_score(logreg, X, y, cv=loo)
print(scores)
```

The features are categorical values, while the target value is a float value. I am not exactly sure why I am ONLY getting zeros.

The data looks like this before creating dummy variables

```
N level,species,Plant Weight(g)
L,brownii,0.3008
L,brownii,0.3288
M,brownii,0.3304
M,brownii,0.388
M,brownii,0.406
H,brownii,0.3955
H,brownii,0.3797
H,brownii,0.2962
```

Updated code where I am still getting zeros:

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Creating dummies for the non numerical features in the dataset

df = pd.read_csv("Flaveria.csv")
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["N level", "species"], drop_first=True)

# Extracting the target value from the dataset
X = df.iloc[:, df.columns != "Plant Weight(g)"]
y = df.iloc[:, 0]

forest = RandomForestRegressor()
loo = LeaveOneOut()

scores = cross_val_score(forest, X, y, cv=loo)
print(scores)
```

Comment: LogisticRegression is a classifier. For float (continuous) values, try regression. See the scikit estimators ending with Regressor.

Comment: I changed the LogisticRegression to RandomForestRegressor, but I am still getting zeros?

Comment: Please include a small sample of your dataset that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Please share the data

Comment: Edited in the data

Comment: Your target (plant weight) is continuous.  LogisticRegressor is not an appropriate model to use in this context.

Comment: I know, I changed it to RandomTreeRegressor

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven, please update your code to show exactly what you are running because you should no longer be getting zeros.

Comment: I am still getting zeros. However, when i changed from LeaveOneOut to Kfold with n_folds = 5, I got this result = [-3.37596122 -0.58236105 -9.0212849  -0.65050534 -0.67190447]. Does that seem right? Also, I updated the main post with the code where I am still getting zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general `cross_val_score` will split the data into train and test with the given iterator, then fit the model with the train data and score on the test fold. And for regressions, [`r2_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) is the default in scikit.

You have specified `LeaveOneOut()` as your `cv` iterator. So each fold will contain a single test case. In this case, R_squared will always be 0.

Looking at the [formula for R2 in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions):

```
R2 = 1 - (SS_res/SS_tot)
```

And

```
SS_tot = sqr(sum(y - y_mean))
```

Here for a single case, `y_mean` will be equal to `y` value and hence denominator is 0. So the whole R2 is undefined (Nan). In this case, scikit-learn will set the value to 0, instead of `nan`.

Changing the LeaveOneOut() to any other CV iterator like KFold, will give you some non-zero results as you have already observed.