# Python Numpy array (bad) automatic rounding

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using Leave-One-Out-Cross-Validation on a Linear Regression model.
Having 8869 observations, as a result of the following:

```
reg = LinearRegression()

list_Rs = cross_val_score(reg, X_34_const, y_34,
                      cv = len(y_34), 
                      scoring = 'r2')
```

I should obtain a numpy array of 8869 values included between 0 and 1, with 8 decimals.
The problem is that, in producing the result, Python automatically rounds all such values to 0.0:

```
array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])
```

while instead, for instance, if I use a 2-fold-cross-validation (which implies list_Rs beinga a numpy array with 2 values), it prints the correctly not rounded values:

```
list_Rs = cross_val_score(reg, X_34_const, y_34,
                      cv = 2, 
                      scoring = 'r2')
```

which, printed, is:

```
array([0.16496198, 0.18115719])
```

This is not simply a printing representation, problem, since, for instance:

```
print(list_Rs[3] == 0)
```

returns True. This is for me a major problem since, in my computations, I will then need to put the values of list_Rs at the denominator of a fraction!

How can I solve the problem so to not have automatically rounded values also in my 8869 dimensional array?

Many thanks and I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a score of zero using cross val score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605956/getting-a-score-of-zero-using-cross-val-score)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Python nor NumPy is doing any rounding here: scikit-learn's [`r2_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) scoring function (which is invoked under the hood when calling `cross_val_score` with `scoring='r2'`) is returning actual zeros.

That's because by using leave-one-out, each validation set consists of a single sample. So now for each fold of your cross validation, `r2_score` is being called with a single observed value along with a single predicted value for that observation. And in that situation, it produces zero. For example:

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y_true = np.array([2.3])
>>> y_pred = np.array([2.1])
>>> r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
0.0
```

[Here's](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dbac82d362f296dc2746f10e43ffa1615660/sklearn/metrics/regression.py#L554-L556) the portion of the implementation where `r2_score` ends up (somewhat arbitrarily) returning zero when evaluated on a single data point, assuming that the predicted value isn't an exact match for the observed value.

Arguably, `r2_score` should be either raising an exception or producing negative infinity rather than zero here: the coefficient of determination uses the variance of the observed data as a normalising factor, and when there's only a single observation, that variance is zero, so the formula for the R2 score involves a division by zero. There's some discussion of this in a [scikit-learn bug report](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5097).

Comment: Dear Mark, many thanks for your answer. You're indeed right, on one single observation the total sum of squares is clearly 0, which should then yield a negative infinity R^2 or more generally an error. A part from the fact that even in regular situations the R^2 is already a bad and widely misused measure, I think I will then simply consider the MSE of the observation or the R^2 of the entire regression, to be used as a proxy of goodness of fit in my subsequent computations.